# How can I use Pageable in @RestController?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, pagination, spring-rest

I know the `Pageable` comes from `spring-data-` domain.

Is there any elegant way to directly use `org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable` in `@RestController`?

I tried following.

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET,
                path = "pageable",
                produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<Pageable> readPageable(@NotNull final Pageable pageable) {
    return ResponseEntity.ok(pageable);
}
```

The result is not what I expected.

```
...: ~ $ curl -X GET --header 'Accept: application/json' 'http://localhost:8080/.../pageable?limit=1&offset=1' | python -mjson.tool
...
{
    "offset": 0,
    "pageNumber": 0,
    "pageSize": 20,
    "sort": null
}
```

Comment: what response you want?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It should return not Pageable but Page.

```
public Page<YourEntityHere> readPageable(@NotNull final Pageable pageable) {
    return someService.search(pageable);
}
```

Pageable is request side which contains what exactly you need. But Page contains results.

See for example [the link](http://www.javainuse.com/spring/SpringBootUsingPagination)