# how to make saveAll result returning pageable?

Tags: java, spring-boot, pageable

I have an API (POST) that as a result is returning a list of 90 objects, therefore I want to return a pageable result and I do no how

```
public ResponseDto<Plans> createlPlans(){
-------
return new ResponseDto(PlanRepository.saveAll(PlanList))}
```

Comment: please check : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47087415/how-can-i-use-pageable-in-restcontroller

Comment: @dassum I need to make pageable after a result of a POST request, I mean in saveAll not in find (Get)

Answer (score 0):

Check out this snippet from `SimpleJpaRepository.class`

```
@Transactional
public <S extends T> List<S> saveAll(Iterable<S> entities) {
    Assert.notNull(entities, "Entities must not be null!");
    List<S> result = new ArrayList();
    Iterator var3 = entities.iterator();

    while(var3.hasNext()) {
        S entity = var3.next();
        result.add(this.save(entity));
    }

    return result;
}
```

The items are being added to the new ArrayList.
There are no overloaded methods as well, which is why I think there is no way for you to achieve the behaviour.

You can, however, get the sublist and return. (custom approach)